# Using an API to Extract All Comments from a Reddit Post

Tags: r, api

I am using the Reddit API (Pushshift) : https://github.com/pushshift/api

Using the documentation, I understand how I can use this to extract every comment containing the word "covid" that was left in a certain time period:

```
https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment?q=covid&after=3h&before=2h&size=1
```

The output looks something like this:

```
{"data":[{"subreddit_id":"t5_2qh6p","author_is_blocked":false,"comment_type":null,"edited":false,"author_flair_type":"richtext","total_awards_received":0,"subreddit":"Conservative","author_flair_template_id":null,"id":"j98zf27","gilded":0,"archived":false,"collapsed_reason_code":null,"no_follow":false,"author":"VamboRoolOkay","send_replies":true,"parent_id":41917615743,"score":1,"author_fullname":"t2_7uxkru5f","all_awardings":[],"body":"I will never believe that election fraud wasn't a significant factor. Go ahead - call it a conspiracy theory. But I also maintained that Covid was lab-created. Truth is the Daughter of Time.","top_awarded_type":null,"author_flair_css_class":null,"author_patreon_flair":false,"collapsed":false,"author_flair_richtext":[{"e":"text","t":"Conservative"}],"is_submitter":false,"gildings":{},"collapsed_reason":null,"associated_award":null,"stickied":false,"author_premium":false,"can_gild":true,"link_id":"t3_116l7ct","unrepliable_reason":null,"author_flair_text_color":"dark","score_hidden":true,"permalink":"/r/Conservative/comments/116l7ct/kamala_harris_plans_on_running_with_biden_in_2024/j98zf27/","subreddit_type":"public","locked":false,"author_flair_text":"Conservative","treatment_tags":[],"created_utc":1676866031,"subreddit_name_prefixed":"r/Conservative","controversiality":0,"author_flair_background_color":"","collapsed_because_crowd_control":null,"distinguished":null,"retrieved_utc":1676866047,"updated_utc":1676866048,"body_sha1":"328df3784d15f77b98a84418c4ce720822227cfe","utc_datetime_str":"2023-02-20 04:07:11"}],"error":null,"metadata":{"es":{"took":98,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":828,"successful":828,"skipped":824,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":573,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null}},"es_query":{"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[{"simple_query_string":{"fields":["body"],"query":"covid","default_operator":"and"}},{"range":{"created_utc":{"gte":1676862433000}}},{"range":{"created_utc":{"lt":1676866033000}}}]}}]}},"aggs":{},"sort":{"created_utc":"desc"}},"es_query2":"{\"size\":1,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"simple_query_string\":{\"fields\":[\"body\"],\"query\":\"covid\",\"default_operator\":\"and\"}},{\"range\":{\"created_utc\":{\"gte\":1676862433000}}},{\"range\":{\"created_utc\":{\"lt\":1676866033000}}}]}}]}},\"aggs\":{},\"sort\":{\"created_utc\":\"desc\"}}","api_launch_time":1673017478.254743,"api_request_start":1676873233.6143198,"api_request_end":1676873233.7406816,"api_total_time":0.12636184692382812}}
```

**My Question:** Suppose I identify a post that contains the word "covid" - now, I want to retrieve EVERY comment on this post (regardless if it contains the word "covid" or not) : Is this possible to do?

For instance, based on the output of these results, I see that :

- link_id: t3_116l7ct
- parent_id:41917615743

**Can I somehow use this information to write an API query to retrieve all comments from this post?**

I tried the following query but got an empty result: `https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search/?link_id=t3_116cjib`

Thanks!

**Note 1 :** Is it possible to perform this task using a "two stage approach"? E.g. Stage 1 - identify a post where the word "covid" was left in the comments. Stage 2 - begin to extract ALL comments from this post (regardless if they contain "covid" or not)

**Note 2:** I have an R script that I am currently using

```
library(jsonlite)

part1 = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="    
part2 = "h&before="
part3 = "h&size=500"

results = list()
for (i in 1:10)
{tryCatch({
    {
        url_i<-  paste0(part1, i+1,  part2, i,  part3)
        r_i <-  fromJSON(url_i)
      
        results[[i]] <- data.frame(r_i$data$body , r_i$data$id, r_i$data$parent_id, r_i$data$link_id)
        
        #myvec_i <- sapply(results, NROW)
        
        #print(c(i, sum(myvec_i))) 
        print(i)
        #ifelse(i %% 200 == 0, saveRDS(results, "results_index.RDS"), "" )
    }
}, error = function(e){})
}

final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
```

Can I somehow modify this script to get the desired results?

Answer (score 3):

In theory, to accomplish this, I believe you need a several step process:

1. Identify comments mentioning COVID, as you have already done:

   https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment?q=covid&after=3h&before=2h&size=1
2. Identify the submission id associated with each comment, which is embedded in the permalink:

   /r/expats/comments/**11bzdu2**/what_are_the_amenities_you_didnt_realize_youd_be/ja2sk8m/

```
results[[i]] <- data.frame(r_i$data$body , r_i$data$id, r_i$data$parent_id, r_i$data$link_id, r_i$data$permalink)
results[[i]]$sub_id <- sapply(results[[i]]$r_i.data.permalink, function(x) strsplit(x, "/")[[1]][5])
```

3. Identify all comment ids associated with each submission id. The following should work, but unfortunately, the [API appears to be broken](https://github.com/pushshift/api/issues/138).

   https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/submission/comment_ids/11bzdu2
4. Retrieve text for each comment id.

   https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?ids=ja2sk8m

Putting these together should accomplish what you are looking for. Unfortunately, since the API current doesn't work as intended, and old capabilities for listing seem to be broken (replicating the solution shown [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pushshift/comments/qufgqa/get_all_comments_from_a_post_id/) does not work because link_id isn't accepted), it appears that what you are looking for may not currently be possible.

Comment: @ nrp1000: thank you so much for your answer! is this link supposed to work? https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/submission/comment_ids/11bzdu2

Comment: No, unfortunately, that link doesn’t current work, although the api documentation states that it should. This is reported as a bug here: https://github.com/pushshift/api/issues/138 You might consider adding a comment to the bug report as well to amplify that this is an issue. As far as I am aware, you won’t be able to accomplish what you are looking to do until the bug is addressed.

Comment: Update: I have not been able to test, but this workaround may accomplish what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734907/pushshiftapi-not-returning-all-comments

Comment: Of course. Please let us know if that solution works for you.